# problem adding and integrating p5.play to angular and resulted in method not found

Tags: angular, p5.js

I wanted in angular to add p5.play.

The problem was that using:

import * as p5 from 'p5'

did not also include the p5.play methods.

Answer (score 0):

in angular.json:

```
"scripts": [
{
"input": "node_modules/p5/lib/p5.min.js",
"inject": true,
"bundleName": "p5"
},
{
"input": "node_modules/p5/lib/addons/p5.sound.js",
"inject": true,
"bundleName": "p5.sound" },
{
"input": "src/assets/js/p5.play.js",
"inject": true,
"bundleName": "p5.play"
}
]
```

in angular component using p5:

```
declare var p5: any;
```